# Deposit and bond are different notions or not?

Tags: baking

Around Tezos baking documents, I often see words: "deposit" and "bond".  The both seem to be the budget slashed when you misbehave at baking.

Are they exactly the same, or do they have any technical difference?

Comment: The bond is the « safety deposit » aka the pool of money which can be slashed, in whole or in part, depending on the kind of failure of the baker to properly execute its duties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The protocol defines two constants "block_security_deposit" and "endorsement_security_deposit". On mainnet these are currently 512 and 64. These deposits are paid by bakers/endorsers and are frozen for 5 cycles along with the associated rewards.

the command line call to retrieve the constants is:

```
tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/context/constants
```

The term "bond" is not well defined nor used consistently. But most commonly is used to describe the sum of the deposits currently frozen.